Not able to access aws cognito identity pool id from flutter app
I have a simple flutter app that will allow users to take a picture and upload it to my S3 bucket. I have created a AWS Cognito identity pool to allow guest access and have set the correct S3 write access policy there. But when I try to upload to S3 from the app I keep getting the error that the mentioned ID pool id is not found. I am using 'amazon_s3_cognito' package to upload the image to S3.
I/System.out(11855): upload failed
E/AwsRegionHelper(11855): error in upload id [ 1 ] : IdentityPool '[my_id]' not found. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException;)
I/System.out(11855): upload failed

how do I debug this?
I have made sure my region is correct. I also have the correct S3 write policy in place. I am trying to do the upload through an Android emulator in VS code The package versions are: amazon_s3_cognito: ^0.8.1
